# Find all symbols and spaces together between two alphanumeric characters in Python3

Tags: python, regex

In this problem I'm trying to find symbols and spaces between two alphanumeric characters. I am using regular expressions, but I cannot get result as I want. Any valuable tricks for this code is appreciated (only for regex solution):

```
import re
s = "This$#is% Matrix#  %!"
regex_pattern = '\w(.[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:\s]*)\w' # needed to be solve
re.findall(regex_pattern, s)
```

Output is:

```
['h', '$#', '% ', 't']
```

Expected output is:

```
['$#', '% ']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this simple pattern:

```
import re
s = "This$#is% Matrix#  %!"
regex_pattern = '(?<=\w)[^\w]+?(?=\w)'
print(re.findall(regex_pattern, s))
```

Output:

```
['$#', '% ']
```

Basically, the pattern `(?<=\w)[^\w]+?(?=\w)` searches for clumps of all non-alphanumeric characters *(that has to be at least one character in length)* that are between 2 alphanumeric characters.

Comment: More simple and useful one. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 2):

Using a regex find all approach:

```py
s = "This$#is% Matrix#  %!"
matches = re.findall(r'(?<=\w)[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:\s]+(?=\w)', s)
print(matches)  # ['$#', '% ']
```

This approach is similar to yours, except that it simply searches for a sequence of symbols or whitespace characters which are surrounded on both sides by word characters.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex uses quantifier * (0 or more) to match a series of non-alpha chars, so you get matches with no non-alpha characters between; you should use + to match one or more non-alpha chars:

```
import re
s = "This$#is% Matrix#  %!"

regex_pattern = r'\w([@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:\s]+)\w' # needed to be solve
print(re.findall(regex_pattern, s) )
```

Output:

```
['$#', '% ']
```

My 'trick' is is to use e.g. regex101.com to make sure the regex works before going to code, and to build up the regex a step at a time so you know when you add a step and the regex stops matching that it was the most recent step causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your shortest solution is

```py
import re
s = "This$#is% Matrix#  %!"
regex_pattern = r'\b\W+\b'
print( re.findall(regex_pattern, s) ) # => ['$#', '% ']
```

See the [online Python demo](https://ideone.com/m9Boyi).

**Why it works**

- `\b` - the word boundary followed with `\W` pattern matches a location that is right after a word char (i.e. a letter, digit or `_`)
- `\W+` - matches one or more non-word chars, the chars other than letters, digits and underscores
- `\b` - right after `\W`, the word boundary matches a location that is immediately followed with a word char.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/WzS0lX/1).